# How to loop over .dat file and append specific column per set of lines to an array

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, append

In the .dat file, the first line [it’s an integer, I called S) indicates the number of sets present but also the number of variations per set. For example, if S is 21, there are 21 sets present of each 21 lines.

Then, as from the next line there are 6 columns. I want to append the 4th column per set of S lines to an array to make some calculations later on. I want to stop doing that till line S*S. The complication is that I need to ignore (don’t append) every 21st line per set since they’re fictitious results.

I’m not completely sure how to go about it, but here is what I got for now. Grateful for any help.

```
with open('foo.dat') as f:

    S = int(f.readline())  #extracting set number
    print("Sets, S:", S)

    I   = [] 

    for i, lines in enumerate(f):
        columns = lines.split()

        if i < S*S: 

            In = float(columns[3])                                                            
            I.append(In)   #extracting 4th column

    #checking results        
    print(I)
    print("length of I:", len(I))
```

Please find attached link to an example .dat file i’m working with: https://pastebin.com/Cgms3efh

Expected output:

I1 = [140.66758, 46.745557, 20.931668, 10.599119, 5.4772385, 2.9093667, 1.713973, 1.1483754, 0.83311013, 0.62603209, 0.47950916, 0.37391387, 0.29780616, 0.2431309, 0.20399252, 0.17613667, 0.15656772, 0.14322945, 0.13475736, 0.13030334]

I2 = [46.745557, 28.637786, 16.271265, 9.0978727, 4.9856322, 2.7981477, 1.7304986, 1.1918406, 0.87493924, 0.66197242, 0.5100049, 0.39981398, 0.31993277, 0.2622417, 0.22075246, 0.19110705, 0.17021343, 0.1559358, 0.14684993, 0.14206743]

...

NOTE: I actually don't need to have them all saved, since I will do a calculation with them per set before passing on to the next set of 21-1 lines.
So array I could be overwritten for each new set of lines.

Comment: Maybe show a sample of your expected output

Comment: Ok, I'll add it

Comment: Your code workring fine for me. what is issue you are facing?

Comment: @beer44, Right now my code is extracting the whole 4th column till line S*S, but I'm trying to extract them per set of 20 lines and skipping one line in between sets. I'm completely lost on how to approach it.

Comment: So you needto skip each of 21, 41 line, and so on?

Comment: @beer44, indeed, excluding the first line of the .dat file (S integer), I want to skip lines 21, 42, 63, ... from the column section

Comment: @Rahoul check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation with nested list comprehension:

```
with open('test.dat', 'r') as file:
    num = int(file.readline().strip())
    data = [[float(file.readline().split()[3]) for i in range(num)][:-1] for j in range(num)]
```

Then you just access your `data[0]` for first set, `data[1]` for second set, and so on...

```
print(data[0])
# [140.66758, 46.745557, 20.931668, 10.599119, 5.4772385, 2.9093667, 1.713973, 1.1483754, 0.83311013, 0.62603209, 0.47950916, 0.37391387, 0.29780616, 0.2431309, 0.20399252, 0.17613667, 0.15656772, 0.14322945, 0.13475736, 0.13030334]
print(data[1])
# [46.745557, 28.637786, 16.271265, 9.0978727, 4.9856322, 2.7981477, 1.7304986, 1.1918406, 0.87493924, 0.66197242, 0.5100049, 0.39981398, 0.31993277, 0.2622417, 0.22075246, 0.19110705, 0.17021343, 0.1559358, 0.14684993, 0.14206743]
```

If you don't need to store all the data, you can use a generator instead:

```
def set_gen(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        num = int(file.readline().strip())
        for _ in range(num):
            yield [float(file.readline().split()[3]) for i in range(num)][:-1]

my_sets = set_gen('test.dat')
print(next(my_sets))
```

Comment: this is very slick

Comment: Wow, that's some efficiency at its finest! Thanks for the beautifully succinct code

Comment: Python's list/dict comprehension can be very handy.  The more you use them the more it makes sense and better applied in your solutions.  Also see my updated generator solution if you do have a large set of data.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator to work out if your on the 21st element or not. If the number divides exactly by 21 then its the 21st line of the set. To make this more generic i have made the modulo based on the set size.

```
with open('query4.txt') as f:
    sets = int(f.readline())  #extracting set number
    limit = sets * sets
    items = []
    print("Sets:", sets, ", limit:", limit)

    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        columns = line.split()
        num = float(columns[3])
        #add one to the index and check if its divisable by the set size.
        if (index + 1) % sets:
            #we got here if this number cannot be devided by the set sizze without a remainder I.E this line is not the last line of the set
            items.append(num)  # extracting 4th column 
        else:
            #we got here if we are on the last line of the set size so print the dta and reset the list.
            print(items)
            items = []
        if index > limit:
            #break the loop when we reach the limit
            break
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
Sets: 21 , limit: 441
[140.66758, 46.745557, 20.931668, 10.599119, 5.4772385, 2.9093667, 1.713973, 1.1483754, 0.83311013, 0.62603209, 0.47950916, 0.37391387, 0.29780616, 0.2431309, 0.20399252, 0.17613667, 0.15656772, 0.14322945, 0.13475736, 0.13030334]
[46.745557, 28.637786, 16.271265, 9.0978727, 4.9856322, 2.7981477, 1.7304986, 1.1918406, 0.87493924, 0.66197242, 0.5100049, 0.39981398, 0.31993277, 0.2622417, 0.22075246, 0.19110705, 0.17021343, 0.1559358, 0.14684993, 0.14206743]
[20.931668, 16.271265, 11.032549, 6.8871422, 4.1249159, 2.5314457, 1.684505, 1.2087469, 0.90466792, 0.69278056, 0.53932924, 0.42681753, 0.34438866, 0.28428271, 0.24069443, 0.20932984, 0.18709735, 0.171836, 0.16209171, 0.15695167]
```

Comment: Ah nice, that's something I'm more familiar with. Thank you very much!